# Definition of vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I learnt that `a vector is a sequence of data elements of the same basic type.` Then what will we call `a` in the following code (as it contains both numeric and charater):

```
a = c(1,"b")
is.vector(a)
[1] TRUE
```

So is the definition of vector wrong? I referred [this tutorial.](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector)

Comment: You didn't bother to read the help text. `?c`: "All arguments are coerced to a common type which is the type of the returned value"; "The output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression.". Try `class(a)`.

Comment: In order to avoid confusion, you should also study `help("is.vector")` carefully. `is.vector` (with default settings) doesn't conform to your definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial simplifies and that can cause confusion. Its definition describes "basic vector types", but there are also "generic vectors".

From the [language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html) (which you should study):

> 2.1.1 Vectors
>
> Vectors can be thought of as contiguous cells containing data. Cells
>   are accessed through indexing operations such as x[5]. More details
>   are given in Indexing.
>
> R has six basic (‘atomic’) vector types: logical, integer, real,
>   complex, string (or character) and raw. The modes and storage modes
>   for the different vector types are listed in the following table.

```
typeof    mode      storage.mode 
logical   logical   logical
integer   numeric   integer 
double    numeric   double 
complex   complex   complex
character character character 
raw       raw       raw
```

> Single numbers, such as 4.2,
>   and strings, such as "four point two" are still vectors, of length 1;
>   there are no more basic types. Vectors with length zero are possible
>   (and useful).
>
> 2.1.2 Lists
>
> Lists (“generic vectors”) are another kind of data storage. Lists have
>   elements, each of which can contain any type of R
>   object, i.e. the elements of a list do not have to be of the same
>   type. List elements are accessed through three different indexing
>   operations. These are explained in detail in Indexing.
>
> Lists are vectors, and the basic vector types are referred to as
>   atomic vectors where it is necessary to exclude lists.

From `help("is.vector")`:

> If mode = "any", is.vector may return TRUE for the atomic modes, list
>   and expression. For any mode, it will return FALSE if x has any
>   attributes except names. [...]

(An `expression` is basically a `list`.)

> Note that factors are not vectors; is.vector returns FALSE and as.vector converts a factor to a character vector for mode = "any".

Finally, as @Henrik points out, `c` coerces all arguments to the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in your example, the "1" will be viewed as a character by R.

> a<-c(1,"b")
>   typeof(a[1])
>   [1] "character"

Comment: this is already stated (although somewhat obliquely) by @Roland's answer.